# Config file doesn't create after installation of scully

Tags: angular, scully

I created a new App Angular (version 16.1.8) and I installed Scully (version 2.1.41).

There was no error during the installation but the config file `scully.<projectName>.config.ts` wasn't created.

I open a [issue](https://github.com/scullyio/scully/issues/1669) an issue on the [official repository](https://github.com/scullyio/scully).

If anyone has any idea how to solve the problem, that would be really nice.